# How to split a string and insert each value as a new record with Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Given a string of categories, I need to split the string and insert each separate item as a new record using EF.

The following does not work since string cannot be converted to Tag:

```
Dim s = "Books, Novels, Magazines"
s.Split(", ").ToList.ForEach(Function(x) _rdsqlconn.Tags.Add(x))
```

I have googled and not found an answer to my dilemma. How can i split the string and insert each as a new tag record?

Comment: well what is a `Tag` record? Can't really help you if you don't show what your entity looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your Tag class has a property to which the string value is to be assigned.

This should work:

```
Dim s = "Books, Novels, Magazines"
s.Split(", ").ToList.ForEach(Function(x) _rdsqlconn.Tags.Add(New Tag With { .Value = x });
```

Edit: Had to look up the VB.NET object initializer syntax. Make sure you replace "Value" with whatever property your need to use and also make sure you leave the period in front of the property name.

Comment: That was it. Thanks TerminalFrost